# Can the tangent and cotangent bundles have the same coordinates? Symplectic form in cotangent coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation, hamilton-equations

This is somewhat related to another question I asked at [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4575173/is-a-general-state-space-a-manifold).

In classical mechanics, the configuration of some mechanical systems (say, a double pendulum) can be described by a point on an *n*-dimensional smooth configuration manifold, $Q$. The dynamics are then often studied using Lagrangian mechanics on $TQ$, or using Hamiltonian mechanics on $T^*Q$, both of which have coordinate representations in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. Let's let $(\pmb{x},\dot{\pmb{x}})$ be some coordinate representation for $(\text{x},\mathbf{v})\in TQ$ and $(\pmb{q},\pmb{p})$ be some coordinate representation for $(\text{x},\mathbf{p})\in T^*Q$ (in general, $\pmb{q}\neq\pmb{x}$).  That is, there are some smooth coordinate charts, $(TQ,\varphi)$ and $(T^*Q,\vartheta)$ (not necessarily defined globally):

$$
\varphi:TQ \to \mathbb{R}^{2n} \quad,\quad   (\pmb{x},\dot{\pmb{x}}) = \varphi(\text{x},\mathbf{v}) \quad \leftrightarrow \quad  (\text{x},\mathbf{v}) = \varphi^{-1}(\pmb{x},\dot{\pmb{x}})
\\
\vartheta:T^*Q \to \mathbb{R}^{2n} \quad,\quad  (\pmb{q},\pmb{p}) = \vartheta(\text{x},\mathbf{p})  \quad \leftrightarrow \quad  (\text{x},\mathbf{p}) = \vartheta^{-1}(\pmb{q},\pmb{p}) 
$$

But, typically, the ``Lagrangian state space'' coordinates, $(\pmb{x},\dot{\pmb{x}})$, are diffeomorphic to the phase space coordinates, $(\pmb{q},\pmb{p})$; there is some $\psi : \mathbb{R}^{2n}\to \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ (not necessarily defined globally) such that:
$$
\psi : \mathbb{R}^{2n}\to \mathbb{R}^{2n} \quad, \quad  (\pmb{q},\pmb{p}) = \psi(\pmb{x},\dot{\pmb{x}})  \quad \leftrightarrow \quad  (\pmb{x},\dot{\pmb{x}}) = \psi^{-1}(\pmb{q},\pmb{p})
$$

So this means that $(\pmb{x},\dot{\pmb{x}})$ can also be mapped to $T^*Q$ and $(\pmb{q},\pmb{p})$ can be mapped to $TQ$:

$$
(\text{x},\mathbf{v}) = \varphi^{-1} \circ \psi^{-1}(\pmb{q},\pmb{p}) \quad \leftrightarrow \quad   (\pmb{q},\pmb{p}) = \psi \circ \varphi(\text{x},\mathbf{v})
\\
(\text{x},\mathbf{p}) = \vartheta^{-1} \circ \psi(\pmb{x},\dot{\pmb{x}}) \quad \leftrightarrow \quad   (\pmb{x},\dot{\pmb{x}}) = \psi^{-1} \circ \vartheta(\text{x},\mathbf{p})
$$

**A.)** So it seems that $TQ$ and $T^*Q$, which are supposedly very distinct spaces, can both be described using the same coordinates. This seems wrong to me for some reason. Is it?

**B.) (this is my main question)** In particular, let's take $\pmb{x}=\pmb{q}$ as the same coordinates for $Q$. The canonical symplectic form on $T^*Q$ is given in symplectic coordinates $(\pmb{q},\pmb{p})$ by
$$
  \omega = \mathbf{d}q^i \wedge \mathbf{d}p_i \; \in \Omega^2(T^*Q)
$$
We have a coordinate transformation  $(\pmb{q},\dot{\pmb{q}})\mapsto (\pmb{q},\frac{\partial L }{\partial \dot{\pmb{q}}}) = (\pmb{q},\pmb{p}) $ such that the above can be written in the  $(\pmb{q},\dot{\pmb{q}})$ coordinates as

$$
  \omega = \mathbf{d}q^i \wedge \mathbf{d}p_i \;=\;  a_{ij} \mathbf{d}q^i \wedge \mathbf{d}q^j \,+\, b_{ij}\mathbf{d}q^i \wedge \mathbf{d}\dot{q}^j
$$

where $a_{ij} = \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial q^j \partial\dot{q}^i}$ and $b_{ij} = \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial \dot{q}^j \partial\dot{q}^i}$. **I have seen several books say that the above expression for $\omega$ is actually a totally *different* 2-form that belongs to $\Omega^2(TQ)$ rather than $\Omega^2(T^*Q)$. Why?**

**C.)** So when working directly with coordinates and equations of motion in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, how do we know if we are working with coordinate representations of $TQ$ or $T^*Q$? If you start with coordinates on $TQ$, then do some transformation(s) in coordinate space, how can you tell if you have ``accidentally'' jumped to $T^*Q$, or vice versa?

---

*edit:* I know that $(\pmb{x},\dot{\pmb{x}})$ are not  *symplectic* coordinates for $T^*Q$. But it seems like, if they are valid coordinates for $TQ$, then they are also valid coordinates for $T^*Q$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I suppose I mean that some 2n-tuple of coordinates which are mapped to a  point on $TQ$ can also be mapped to a point on $T^*Q$ (under different mappings).  For a particle on $Q=\mathbb{E}^2$, we can consider $(\pmb{q},\dot{\pmb{q}})=(r,\phi,\dot{r},\dot{\phi})$ and $(\pmb{q},\pmb{p})= (r,\phi ,p_r, p_{\phi}) \equiv (r,\phi, m\dot{r}, mr^2\dot{\phi})$.  Both sets of coordinates specify the exact same state, which is an abstract point on $TQ$ or $T^*Q$. But it seems that either coordinates can be used for (mapped to) either space.

Comment: But yes, my question is not posed well because I'm still not 100% sure what I'm confused about. The main reason I am asking is for question B in my post, if you can offer any clarity on it.

Comment: ahh ok, I'm aware of the Legendre transformation, but only as the "passive'' coordinate transformation on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ that gave in my post. It seems I need to learn the "active'' coordinate-free view of it as a map $TQ \to T^*Q$.  That would indeed clarify things.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez  YES! That is my confusion. I learned all of analytical mechanics (Lagrangian and Hamiltonian formulations) only in terms of coordinates on some $\mathbb{R}^m$. I'm now trying to teach myself the  geometric view on manifolds.  But, since  ''everything is a function of everything'' on $\mathbb{R}^{m}$, it is not clear which things I learned in the past are coordinate representations for $TQ$ and which are  coordinate representations for $T^*Q$.

Comment: based on my answer to your other question, the answers here should hopefully be obvious. For (A), since the spaces are different, the coordinates are different (since coordinates are by definition functions defined on a subset of that space), though as I mentioned to you, you’re pulling back the same base coordinates on $Q$ to $TQ$ and $T^*Q$, but people often abuse notation here. For (B), you take the symplectic form $\omega\in \Omega^2(T^*Q)$, and you consider the pullback by the Fiber-derivative, $\omega_L=(\mathbf{F}L)^*\omega\in \Omega^2(TQ)$. Hence, they’re completely different 2-forms.

Comment: (which by the way is none other than the exterior derivative of the “momentum 1-form” I told you about in the other answer, $d\mu_L=d(\mathbf{F}L^*(\theta))=(\mathbf{F}L)^*(d\theta)=(\mathbf{F}L)^*\omega$, since exterior derivatives commute with pullbacks). For (C), you just need to read the surrounding context, and you need some experience to decipher and get used to the occasional sloppiness and abuse in notation and language. But if you’re using $(q,\dot{q})$, you’re in $TQ$‘s coordinates, while if you use $(q,p)$, you’re in $T^*Q$‘s coordinates.